# No Puedo comparar la respuesta AJAX jquery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto web en php y ajax de JQUERY el problema que tengo es en el siguiente código :

```
$.ajax({
        url: ruta,
        type: 'POST',
        data: img,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    })
    .done(function(res) {


            if(res==="a"){
                $("#error-img").html("Error, el archivo no es una imagen");
                $("#error-img").addClass('text-danger');

            }else if(res==="b"){
                $("#error-img").html("Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB");
                $("#error-img").addClass('text-danger');

            }else if(res==="c"){
                $("#error-img").html("Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB");
                $("#error-img").addClass('text-danger');

            }else if(res==="d"){
                $("#error-img").html("Error la anchura y la altura maxima permitida es 500px");
                $("#error-img").addClass('text-danger');    

            }else if(res==="e"){
                $("#error-img").html("Error la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es 60px");
                $("#error-img").addClass('text-danger');

            }else{

                $("#error-img").html("Imagen subida con exito");
                $("#error-img").addClass('text-success');
            }



    });
```

El archivo php me devuelve un string lo que deseo es compararlo por medio de if() pero no lo hace solo lanza el else y no compara alguien me puede decir porque no puedo. TENGO UNA SOSPECHA DE QUE TAL VEZ ES POR ESTO :

```
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
```

Por favor espero su pronta ayuda me estoy volviendo loco

Comment: Hacé un `console.log(res)` antes del primer `if` y fijate que devuelve.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, ya lo hice y me devuelve el string pero a la hora de comparar solo me devuelve el else y no compara a que se debera?

Comment: Probá usar `==` en vez de `===`, tal vez lo que te está devolviendo la consulta de `AJAX` no es exactamente un string y por eso falla la comparación estricta.

Comment: Puede que los datos vengan con espacios sobrantes, prueba a limpiar los valores con `trim`, por ejemplo: `if(res.trim()==="a"){`... Como comentario, yo usaría un `switch` en este caso y eliminaría todo el código redundante, por ejemplo, las segundas líneas de los `if`.

Comment: Si yo estaba usando switch pero tampoco leía la respuesta, ahora e intentado cambiar el contenType="html", pero el resultado es vacio en console.log(res)

Comment: A. Cedano eres un super maestro MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS, CON 'dataType: "html" ' y '.trim()' LOGRE SOLUCIONARLO ahora si funciona GRACIAS POR TU AYUDAAA!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo de `contentType: false` no debería ser problema.

Si quieres, puedes agregar `dataType: "html"` a la petición Ajax.

En cuanto a las comparaciones, puede que el valor te esté viniendo del servidor con espacios sobrantes. Entonces limpia la variable con `trim`.

Aprovecho para mejorar un poco el código:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ruta,
    type: 'POST',
    data: img,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
})
.done(function(res) {

        var res=res.trim();
        var txtClase='text-danger';
        var txtHtml="";

        switch (res) {
            case "a":
                        txtHtml='Error, el archivo no es una imagen';
                        break;
            case "b":
                        txtHtml='Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB';
                        break;
            case "c":
                        txtHtml='Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB';
                        break;

            case "d":
                        txtHtml='Error la anchura y la altura maxima permitida es 500px';
                        break;

            case "e":
                        txtHtml='Error la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es 60px';
                        break;

            default:
                        txtHtml='Imagen subida con exito';
                        txtClase='text-success';
        }

        $("#error-img").html(txtHtml);
        $("#error-img").addClass(txtClase);

});
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias hermano te pasaste de bueno, espero contar contigo para una próxima locura jejeje

Comment: Bienvenido @ArellanoCornejoDaniel, aquí hay bastante gente capacitada que podrá ayudarte en futuros problemas. Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta a mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el centro de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: yo tenia justamente el mismo problema y lo resolví aplicando el "trim" a la variable tal como lo recomendaron, gracias por sus consejos.