# como validar un dato que esta dentro de una db que se ingresa en un formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo creado un formulario que se tiene que rellenar para una inscripción de una competencia pero se tiene que elegir un numero , el cual es único y se guarda en la base datos , lo que quiero hacer es que cuando este ingresando los datos valide si ese numero no esta en la db y si esta le arroje un mensaje que ese numero si esta utilizado

[image: la tabla que estoy utilizando]

```
<form action="guardarNumero.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <!-- AQUI SE TIENE QUE HACER LA VALIDACION -->
            <input type="text" name="numero"  class="form-control" placeholder="numero de participacion" minlength="1" maxlength="3" required autofocus>
          </div></form>
```

Comment: *...cuando este ingresando los datos valide...* esto suena a una [validación con Javascript o Ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/150953/80870), la cual requiere un cierto conocimiento. En caso contrario, la validación sencilla es ejecutar el *Submit*, luego verificar con una consulta si ese numero ya existe, y si es así volver al formulario reimprimiendo los demás datos ya suministrados por el usuario.

Comment: Sería mejor que añades el código de **guardarNumero.php** así te pueden ayudar mejor. Ya que allí podrías comprobar si el numero existe o no en la BD y devolver o un mensaje de error si existe o la acción que deseas si no existe.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con

```
$sql="select * from Nombre_de_Tu_BD where nroPiloto=".$numero;

$res=mysql_query($sql,$conexion);

if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0){

    //  La búsqueda no arrojó usuarios con ese Numero piloto.

}
```

Comment: esto va dentro del input ?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [answer].  Tu respuesta ha sido catalogada como de baja calidad por los usuarios del sitio debido a la falta de una explicación más detallada de cómo implementar esta solución. Las respuestas con solo código no son bien recibidas, lo siento.